# required directive not working on select tag in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, ng-required

I have a form will multiple fields that have the `required` directive attached like so:

```
<input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Business City" data-ng-model="$ctrl.formData.city" required>
```

All are working except the `select` dropdown. I have it so default text displays, prompting users to select from the drop-down. Though the form comes back as valid, even when the user hasn't selected an option from the dropdown. Here is the `select` html.

```
<select name="timezone" id="timezone" class="form-control font-body pill-radius"
    data-ng-model="$ctrl.formData.timezone"
    data-ng-options="zone.abbr for zone in $ctrl.ustimezones"
    required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select timezone</option>
</select>
```

**Question**

Why is the required directive not being detected, thus resulting in the form being valid, allowing the user to submit? I have tried `ng-required="true"` and I am getting the same issue.

Comment: The `select` dop-down is being filled with options from `$ctrl.ustimezones`?

Comment: It doesn't prevent `ng-submit`, you have to check for it in your callback like `if (formData.$invalid) { return; } else { await service.saveWhatever(whatever); }`

Comment: Yeah it's being populate by `$ctrl.ustimezones`. @AluanHaddad sorry I don't understand. I disable my submit button if the form is invalid like so: `<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Create account" data-ng-disabled="registrationForm.$invalid">`. If the form is invalid, it will be disabled.

Comment: That should be working. If you look at the documentation, they have live examples you can even edit, they work. It should be `$ctrl.registrationForm.$invalid` in the template though.

Comment: I've had a look and that's why I'm confused/stuck

Comment: Have you tried the basics? `<pre>{{$ctrl.registrationForm | json}}</pre>`. That will show you every property of the form. https://plnkr.co/edit/URGxF633kD2KOkJ5

Comment: Ahhhhh I have found my issue. I am using views within the multi-paged form. So it wasn't just the select that wasn't working. I may have to do what you suggested @AluanHaddad. Use a callback and check the form data from the controller